# Need Image Tiles

Tags: image

During a recent move to The Cloud, our organization's photos ~ hundreds of them from annual meetings and events ~ were uploaded by default to a document library instead of an image library. We cannot find a way to display photo tiles in the document library, so we cannot see these photos as tiles.

Is there a way to show tiles in a document library? If not, how can we transfer all of these photos en masse to an image library? We are using SharePoint 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not by "Manage Content and Structure"?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new image library

Library Tab of ribbon --> open with explorer

do this for both libraries

Cut and paste